# global.asax function not calling from Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, iis

I am writing a function in global.asax file which needs to be called from the thread which is declared inside the application_start.
It works fine in my debug mode, however not calling the callback function when hosted.

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        writeLog("Application Initialized")
        writeLog("Thread is starting....")
        Dim T As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf UpdateQueue)
        T.Start()
        writeLog("Thread Started....")
    End Sub
    Sub UpdateQueue()
        writeLog("UpdateQueue entry")
        While Q.Count > 0
         ' Some logic
        End While
        writeLog("UpdateQueue going for idle state")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        UpdateQueue()
    End Sub
```

I see the log file like
Thread Starting
Thread Started

but no other message which are printed in "UpdateQue" function
I have tried other methods also.
1. Using Timers: Same issue as above
2. Using Thread.Timers: Same issue as abovee
3. Call the UpdateQueue function directly from application_start: Entering to UpdateQue function and writes to log entry.

I unable to figure out why the issue in server. I am using IIS 7 in my public IP (not from hosting provider) so I can make any changes if required.

Comment: Eventually you'll get a stack overflow due to recursion of `UpdateQueue`.

Comment: What's in `writeLog()`? Maybe there is a lock.

Comment: writeLog simply writes to a file, and not locking itself

Comment: can you suggest me, how do I do that background processing

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET does not work like a desktop application. You can't start a thread and let it run by itself. Application Start gets called when a user performs a request and the app pool is asleep. When it wakes, Application Start gets called, but as soon as the function is done any threads you create will be terminated by the time the rest of the user's request/response is completed.

The simplest way I can put it is that any threads you start on an HTTP Request must be terminated before that user's request/response is completed otherwise you'll get 'Thread was aborted' exception errors.

Where I have found the greatest use for threading in ASP.NET is in working with external resources (such as APIs). If you need to tap multiple external resources in a call, you can get them all going at once, but you MUST .join them before the request/response has completed.

Answer (score 0):

after uploading code on hosted server, you will need to restart IIS server

START Menu > RUN > iisreset